# derivative with integrals proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$,$g: [a,b]→R$ are continuous and differentiable, with $f'$ and $g'$ continuous, on $(a,b)$.

How do I prove that $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ $\int_{a}^x f(t)g'(t)dt$ = $\dfrac{d}{dx}[ f(x)g(x)-\int_{a}^x f'(t)g(t)dt$]

This seams like a not hard problem, i tried to use product role for differentiation, but for some reason I still didn't come up with a proof, so if anyone can help me, I would really appreciated it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x)g'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x)
$$
by the product rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus.